# MySQL PHP INSERT issue

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have really interesting problem about insert command.

I have a database consisting of two columns which are "id" and "note" and id is primary key and auto incremented.

BUT

I can't insert anything to "note" though I can insert a num to "id".

```
echo '<form method="POST">';
echo            '<table>';
echo                '<thead>';
echo                    '<tr>';
echo                        '<th class="genislik100">Yeni Not Ekle</th>';
echo                        '<th></th>';
echo                        '<th class="metinSag"></th>';
echo                    '</tr>';
echo                '</thead>';

echo                '<tbody>';
echo                    '<tr>';
echo                        '<td>Yeni Not:</td>';
echo                        '<td><input type="text" id="note" name="not" /></td>';
echo                        '<td class="metinSag"></td>';
echo                    '</tr>';

echo                    '<tr>';
echo                        '<td><input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Yeni Notu Ekle!!" /></td>';
echo                        '<td></td>';
echo                        '<td class="metinSag"></td>';
echo                    '</tr>';

echo                '</tbody>';
echo            '</table>';
echo                '<form>';




    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        if($_POST['note'] != ''){

                            $note=$_POST['note'];

                            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("ERROR!!");
                            mysql_select_db("db") or die("COULDN'T FIND IT!!") or die("COULDN'T FIND DB"); 

                            $sql="INSERT INTO meteksan_notlar (note) VALUES ('$note')";
                            mysql_query($sql,$con);

                            echo '<script>alert("OKAY!!");</script>';

                            }else
                            echo "<script>alert('FILL THE BLANK!!');</script>";         

                    }
```

I get "OKAY" alert but when I look to database, there is nothing at "note" column. WHY ??

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Ya gotta love it when you hear the echos of the birds in the mountains. But too many of them in the city, gets a car dirty and fast.

Comment: what should I get from this special sentence ? :D

Comment: It means doing all those echos is pointless and more coding for nothing. Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` to find out what errors out. 
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Doing that will help you spot the errors, of Undefined index. You can do one echo with all this, or none at all and just seperate HTML from PHP.

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\meteksan\admin_sayfasi.php on line 447

I get this

Comment: There you go, time to switch ;-)

Comment: I have posted an answer below that you can look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the typo in

```
<input type="text" id="note" name="not" />
```

which should read as

```
<input type="text" id="note" name="note" />
```

Change your code to the following, in order to reflect the deprecation message you received when I told you to add error reporting in comments.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['note'] != ''){

        $note=$_POST['note'];

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "db")  
              or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

        $sql="INSERT INTO meteksan_notlar (note) VALUES ('$note')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        echo '<script>alert("OKAY!!");</script>';

        }else {
        echo "<script>alert('FILL THE BLANK!!');</script>";
        }        

    }
```

---

- I must note that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

You can also do: (and with protection against SQL injection)

```
$note = stripslashes($_POST['note']);
$note = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['note']);

$sql="INSERT INTO meteksan_notlar (note) VALUES ('$note')";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if($query){
echo '<script>alert("OKAY!!");</script>';
}
else{
echo "There was an error" . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="text" id="note" name="not" />`

name="not" should be name="note"